# Create a rownum column in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I want to create a column in a mySQL table (auto increment), I know how to do that, but when I delete a line, columns must be organized automatically, here is  an example:

```
rownum |  name
------------
1      | aaaa
2      | bbbb
3      | cccc
4      | dddd
```

If I delete the second line the result should be:

```
rownum |  name
------------
1      | aaaa
2      | cccc
3      | dddd
```

not like that:

```
rownum |  name
------------
1      | aaaa
3      | cccc
4      | dddd
```

Is there anyway to do that or do I have to edit the column every time I delete/insert something?

Comment: Suppose your rownum 3 has a reference in anothe table as a FK. row 3 goes, but the FK stays and now refers to the new row 3. Is that a risk you can take?

Comment: so you guys are actually recommending to run DDL changes against a live database because a row goes away ? without knowing if data will be orphaned ? all to close a gap ? it must be a full moon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, tested at my own end -

```
ALTER TABLE test ADD COLUMN id2 int unsigned not null;
SET @a:=0;
UPDATE test SET id2=@a:=@a+1 ORDER BY `rownum`;
ALTER TABLE test DROP rownum;
ALTER TABLE test CHANGE id2 rownum int UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
ADD PRIMARY KEY (rownum);
```

**Before** -

[image: before]

**After** -

[image: after]

**FYI** This query block will change your column structure if noticed in a screenshot, however you can always change the column structuring in an easy single line query run.

Comment: Dude, Trust me, you are the best, that's what i was looking for, working like a charme !!

Answer (score 2):

Why not just create a dummy row number

```
SELECT 
    @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS row_number,
    t.name
FROM    Tbll t
JOIN    (SELECT @curRow := 0) r;
```

So, you don't worry on re-ordering every time there is deletion.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to do that is dropping the primary key column and re-create it. All your rows will be reassigned and they should be in the order they were inserted. Anyway I don't understand why you would do that because if you have any table with foreign key as the column dropped you will have to manually change them. Are you sure you want to do that?

Comment: my table is very and i don't want to edit it each time i do an action so i guess that this is the inly solution

Comment: no. what you do it none of the above unless you want to orphan your data and mess everything up, just because of a gap. this is absurd.

Comment: @baharAyØub yes it is, but i don't think is such a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

you can rearange autoincrement by those steps:

```
 ALTER TABLE your_table DROP rownum;
 ALTER TABLE your_table AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
 ALTER TABLE your_table ADD rownum bigint UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY FIRST;
```

explication:

- drop the column rownum
- set auto_increment to 1
- recreate column rownum with autoincrement in first place